# access resolve data on $state.go() with notify false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an interactive map, with categories and markers associated.
I also have a search form, which allow users to search for markers.

When the user clicks on the result he wants to display, I want to :

1. change the URL to the related category URL
2. display the category related to the marker
3. open the popup marker

Here's the code.

**route.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: basepath('app.html'),
        controller: 'AppController'
    })
    .state('app.category', {
        url: '/c-{categoryId}',
        templateUrl: basepath('pages/category.html'),
        controller: 'categoryController',
        resolve: {
            apiRequest: function($http, $stateParams) {
                return $http.get(App.API_URL + "category/" + $stateParams.categoryId);
            }
        }
    })
;
```

**searchController.js**

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {
    'use strict';

    // callback when the user click on a marker in the search box
    $scope.onSearchSelect = function ($item) {
        $state.go('app.category', {
            categoryId: $item.categoryId
        }, {
            location: "replace",
            inherit: false,
            notify: false
        }).then(function(response) {
            // response
            // would like to access apiRequest data here
            // to display the category + markers + open the popup
        });
    };
}]);
```

Everything works as expected, the URL is changed, the API is called etc...
The unique problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the API data from the apiRequest resolver (which is called by the "app.category" route)

If you have any clues, or if I'm doing something wrong, please help me :)

Thanks !

Comment: You inject the `apiRequest` object into your controller, and it will contain response of the $http.get request.

Comment: @Chandermani already tried that, but I'm in searchController, I can't pass the resolver of the app.category state, I have an error ("Unknown provider: apiRequestProvider <- apiRequest").

Comment: you should inject apiRequest into categoryController

Comment: @RaeefRefai It's already the case and my categoryController works fine, but with "notify: false", the categoryController isn't called